# NAV 2017 ODATA V4 not supporting PUT/PATCH?

Tags: dynamics-nav

I am trying to use the returned ETag / the @odata.etag value from GET response and feed into http header while updating an entity(think of PUT/PATCH **Customer** endpoint) through POSTMAN(ARCA).

Can someone please share a screenshot or something which might be helpful.

I cannot find any resource that actually sheds some light on this issue that I am facing.

It gives me a response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Could not validate the client concurrency token required by the service. Please provide a valid token in the client request."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the E.Tag is as follows:

E.Tag : W/\"JzQ0O2l0cW4vNm42NDNSTDVDN3lRLzVEZ1J1c2lYUlhwOExscsFgUEFxazhVQjg9MTswMDsn\"

then remove the escape character from E.Tag and add in header

If-Match : W/"JzQ0O2l0cW4vNm42NDNSTDVDN3lRLzVEZ1J1c2lYUlhwOExwcUFoUEFxazhVQjg9MTswMDsn"